# Looking for a way to reseed batch %random%

Tags: random, batch-file, media, filenames

I'm looking for a random function in batch that I can tack onto the beginning of a filename. I'm creating several thousand symbolic links and I intend to randomize the sorted results by appending a random number to the beginning of the filename.

I have used this function in my nested for loops (iterating through all files in all subdirs):

```
mklink "%LINKDIR%\%random%%%f" "%%f"
```

It returns almost what I want. Unfortunately each symbolic link has the same starting random number. Is there anyway to reseed the %random% value?

Answer (score 3):

Use delayed expansion. I.e. put

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

at the start of your batch file and then use `!random!` instead of `%random%`. See `help set` for a detailed explanation of the topic.

The point here is that `%random%` gets expanded when the `for` loop is *parsed*; thus for subsequent iterations (i.e. when the loop is actually *run*) there is no variable there anymore, just the value. This is fixed by delayed expansion.